# How to insert without giving column names but not giving identity column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test
(
    "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1),
    "SomeColumn" character(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.test
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I am trying this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.test VALUES ('testData');
```

But PostgreSQL throws this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "testData"
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.test VALUES ('testData');

I know this is valid in SQL Server. Is there a way the achieve this behaviour in PostgreSQL?

I do not want to specify the column names. Columns are defined in the order, but the identity column does not exist in the query.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to not give the column names

That's a bad idea. You should **always** specify the target columns for an INSERT statement. Especially if you want to skip some, but not others.

However, if you insist on bad coding style, you can use the `DEFAULT` keyword

```
INSERT INTO public.test VALUES (DEFAULT, 'testData');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this is not a coding style. The data sql queries that i work with is the format that i mention. I must insert this queries into the table without changing it

Comment: Yes it works but it is not the answer i am looking for :(

Comment: Well, the only other option is to move the `Id` column to the end of the table. But still: if you don't specify the target columns this **is** going to fail one day or the other. You should really change your application to properly specify the target columns. That is the only sensible solution to this.

Comment: i couldnt explain my style :) the data which i mean comes with sql queries in the format that insert statements are not my code. They are comming from OUTSIDE. I am giving the primary key to each row. I created table for that data and then i will process this data. i hope that i tell myself correctly at this time :) and also without enough knowlegde dont jugde the other peoples coding styles

Comment: Well, SQL Server's behaviour ("ignoring" or "skipping" the identity column) violates the behaviour of an INSERT statement required by the SQL standard. Postgres complies with the SQL standard and and matches the values specified to the columns in the target table in the order how the columns are defined. There is no way you can get those statements to work with Postgres (or any other DBMS that complies with the SQL standard) **and** keep the identity column at the first position.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The SQL Standard specifies ways to ignore user provided values, like the `OVERRIDING USER VALUE` clause of `INSERT` (and its counterparts `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` to override system values even if it is a _generated always_ identity), and PostgreSQL supports that, but even then you will have to account for the column.

Comment: Yes, but if you omit the column list, the columns are matched by position. And if you use `overriding system values` you have to provide a value for the target column (similar to using the DEFAULT` keyword). However mustafa wants to do neither of those and hopes that the _first_ provided value is magically assigned to the _second_ column of the table (or maybe the first non-identity column). This is simply not going to work.